# Making a Dashboard for admins to manipulate content

Tags: nodes, dashboard

So I started customing the Drupal Dashboard to add nice views of content and site-users to make it user-friendly for the content managers. However when I went to test it with a content manager account, the Dashboard was empty. Upon further research, it would seem that the Dashboard is unique for each user.

Is it possible to create a single Dashboard that will appear for all content managers?

**Edit:**

I'm pretty sure the content managers have enough permissions. They have all permission on content, access to admin bar, access to dashboard, administer blocks, add/delete users.
With these permissions all the stuff I have in the Dashboard should be available to them.

Comment: Dashboard shows the links based upon the permissions, can you check if the proper permissions are assigned to the respective roll

Comment: Please show us your filters applied. AFAIR Dashboard filters by user id by default, so unless you disabled that, indeed they will be different.

Comment: @Mołot Thats gotta be it. I didn't even know there were filters for the dashboard. How can I view/edit them?

Comment: @dan08 Don't remember now, maybe only with module hacking? I hope not, but can't quite test it (it's weekend for me in two minutes! Weee! :D ) I just remember having vaguely similar problem some time ago. Too long time to really post an answer :(